# Extraer contenido de una frase en PHP

Tags: php

Buenos dias, queria preguntaros, como puedo extraer el contenido de una frase en PHP.

Ejemplo:

```
Chandal de pepe por sólo 3,50€
```

**Necesito extraer el precio** de chandal de pepe, los precios a veces puede *contener hasta 3 o 5 digitos y otras veces puede o no contener decimal*. No tengo muy claro si se extrae con un `preg_match()` o con otra funcion en PHP

Comment: El precio siempre esta al final ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero limpia caracteres especiales (tildes etc).
Luego quita todo lo que sean letras.
Sustituye el símbolo €.
Y ahora que solo tienes el numero, castealo a float.

```
<?php


$str = 'Chandal de pepe por sólo 3.50€';
$double = cleanString($str);
$double = preg_replace('/[a-z]/i','',$double); 
$double = str_replace('€','',$double); 

$float = (float)$double;

echo $float; // 122.34343



function cleanString($text) {
    $utf8 = array(
        '/[áàâãªä]/u'   =>   'a',
        '/[ÁÀÂÃÄ]/u'    =>   'A',
        '/[ÍÌÎÏ]/u'     =>   'I',
        '/[íìîï]/u'     =>   'i',
        '/[éèêë]/u'     =>   'e',
        '/[ÉÈÊË]/u'     =>   'E',
        '/[óòôõºö]/u'   =>   'o',
        '/[ÓÒÔÕÖ]/u'    =>   'O',
        '/[úùûü]/u'     =>   'u',
        '/[ÚÙÛÜ]/u'     =>   'U',
        '/ç/'           =>   'c',
        '/Ç/'           =>   'C',
        '/ñ/'           =>   'n',
        '/Ñ/'           =>   'N',
        '/–/'           =>   '-', // UTF-8 hyphen to "normal" hyphen
        '/[’‘‹›‚]/u'    =>   ' ', // Literally a single quote
        '/[“”«»„]/u'    =>   ' ', // Double quote
        '/ /'           =>   ' ', // nonbreaking space (equiv. to 0x160)
    );
    return preg_replace(array_keys($utf8), array_values($utf8), $text);
}

?>
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente Gracias GDP, pero se me olvido algo por alto, y es que a veces puede contener un descuento en el precio y también me gustaría extraer este dato. teniendo como resultado la variable $precio y otra variable $descuento. Os dejo un ejemplo de como seria realmente 
`Chandal de pepe por sólo 3,50€ ¡66% Descuento!`

Comment: @Fumatamax deberías sacar el string entre las exclamaciones. tendrías dos diferentes. Precio y descuenta. Y repites todo el proceso.

Comment: ok voy a probarlo  de sacar el string de las exclamaciones, gracias de nuevo ;)

Comment: Lo he intentado, pero al final me devuelve tanto el valor de los euros como el valor del descuento. A partir de aquí ya no se como sacar el descuento. He repetido el proceso como mencionabas @GDP. Pero he llegado a un punto que me estoy bloquando. He hecho lo siguiente: 
`$triple = cleanString($str);
$triple = preg_replace('/!/i','',$triple); 
$triple = str_replace('%','',$triple); `

Pero devuelve esto **3.50€ 66** ; A partir de aquí no se como extraer el 66 del descuento

Comment: @Fumatamax lanza la pregunta como una nueva (¿cómo sacar separar un string en dos?)

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*(?=[€$])/u
```

- `\d+` 1 o más dígitos.
- `(?:[.,]\d+)*` seguidos de 0 o más repeticiones de:

  - `[.,]\d+` un punto o una coma, seguidos de 1 o más dígitos.
- `(?=[€$])` que esté seguido por (pero que no coincida con) `€` o `$`.
- Modificador `u`: texto y patrón en Unicode (para que coincida con el `€` como único caracter).

Código:

```
$texto = "Chandal de pepe con descuento del 10%, por sólo 3,50€!!!";

if ( preg_match ( '/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*(?=[€$])/u' , $texto, $match ) ) {
    $precio = $match[0];
    echo $precio;
}
```

Resultado:

```
3,50
```